# How to change Seaborn Data Labels to show two decimal places

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

How do I code data labels in a seaborn barplot (or any plot for that matter) to show two decimal places?

I learned how to show data labels from this post:
[Add data labels to Seaborn factor plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444665/add-data-labels-to-seaborn-factor-plot)

But I can't get the labels to show digits.

See example code below:

```
#make the simple dataframe
married = ['M', "NO DATA", 'S']
percentage = [68.7564554, 9.35558, 21.8879646]
df = pd.DataFrame(married, percentage)
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df.columns = ['percentage', 'married']

#make the bar plot
sns.barplot(x = 'married', y = 'percentage', data = df)
plt.title('title')
plt.xlabel('married')
plt.ylabel('Percentage')

#place the labels
ax = plt.gca()
y_max = df['percentage'].value_counts().max() 
ax.set_ylim(1)
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.text(p.get_x() + p.get_width()/2., p.get_height(), '%d' % 
    int(p.get_height()), 
        fontsize=12, color='red', ha='center', va='bottom')
```

Thank you for any help you can provide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use, string formatting with https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language:

```
married = ['M', "NO DATA", 'S']
percentage = [68.7564554, 9.35558, 21.8879646]
df = pd.DataFrame(married, percentage)
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df.columns = ['percentage', 'married']

#make the bar plot
sns.barplot(x = 'married', y = 'percentage', data = df)
plt.title('title')
plt.xlabel('married')
plt.ylabel('Percentage')

#place the labels
ax = plt.gca()
y_max = df['percentage'].value_counts().max() 
ax.set_ylim(1)
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.text(p.get_x() + p.get_width()/2., p.get_height(), '{0:.2f}'.format(p.get_height()), 
        fontsize=12, color='red', ha='center', va='bottom')
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @ScottBoston.  I couldn't find anything in the seaborn docs.  Did I miss it?  Do you have some docs to point me to learn what you just did?

Comment: @Jordan Well, this isn't really a Seaborn issue. It is doing string formatting in python.